# Joining 2 lists into a single view

Tags: list-view, xslt, joined-view

So, I've come across a slight issue that I don't know how to fix in SharePoint 2013, I've been able to join 2 lists into a single view through the use of a Data source, whilst this has provided me with somewhat of a solution there is just one issue I can't figure out...
The column titles are row and milestones, whilst milestones is correct row spans across 5 column names... Has anyone any idea on how to fix this?

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03aBB.png)

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" AsyncRefresh="True" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" Title="D1 Milestone Combination" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{BC5C903B-C592-4ED4-83BD-B96E82D9B855}" id="g_bc5c903b_c592_4ed4_83bd_b96e82d9b855" pagesize="10">
<DataSources>
    <SharePoint:AggregateDataSource runat="server" IsSynchronous="false" SeparateRoot="true" id="New_x0020_D1_x0020_milestones5"><sources><SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"><SelectParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3C2D096A-0EBC-444B-A001-1D10A58AE924}"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3C2D096A-0EBC-444B-A001-1D10A58AE924}"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3C2D096A-0EBC-444B-A001-1D10A58AE924}"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3C2D096A-0EBC-444B-A001-1D10A58AE924}"/></InsertParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource>
        <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"><SelectParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3DE02CA7-DD08-4C06-BDF3-22357774C42A}"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3DE02CA7-DD08-4C06-BDF3-22357774C42A}"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3DE02CA7-DD08-4C06-BDF3-22357774C42A}"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{3DE02CA7-DD08-4C06-BDF3-22357774C42A}"/></InsertParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource>
    </sources><aggregate><concat name="data source"><datasource name="D1_Form" id="0" Type="SPList"/><datasource name="D1_Register" id="1" Type="SPList"/></concat></aggregate></SharePoint:AggregateDataSource>
</DataSources>
<ParameterBindings>
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_nextpagedata" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
</ParameterBindings>


<datafields>@Title,D1 Ref;@Organisation,1.0 Asset Owner;@Address_x0020_of_x0020_Asset,2.0 Street Name of Surplus Asset;@Post_x0020_Code_x0020_of_x0020_A,2.1 Post Code;@UPRN,2.3 UPRN;@XY_x0020_Co_x002d_Ordinates,2.4 XY Co-Ordinates;@Size,2.2 Area of Land (Hectares);@Name,2.15 Main Contact for Inspection;@Tel_x0020_Number_x0020__x0028_fo,2.16 Contact Tel Number;@Email_x0020__x0028_for_x0020_Ins,2.17 Contact Email;@Name_x0020_of_x0020_Legal_x0020_,5.4 Name of Occupier;@Type_x0020_of_x0020_Tenure,5.3 Type of Tenure;@Is_x0020_the_x0020_Land_x0020_Re,4.0 Is the Land Registered?;@Folio_x0020_number,2.5 Folio number(s);@Holder_x0020_of_x0020_Title_x002,4.1a Holder of Title documents;@_x0034__x002e_1a_x003a__x0020_De,6.8 Details;@_x0035__x002e_1_x003a__x0020_Dat,3.0 Date of acquisition from the private sector;@_x0035__x002e_1a_x003a__x0020_Ho,3.1 How the land was acquired;@_x0035__x002e_1b_x003a__x0020_Pu,3.2 Purpose of Acquisition;@_x0035__x002e_2_x003a__x0020_Has,3.3 Material Change;@_x0035__x002e_3_x003a__x0020_Is_,3.4 Is the Asset within Development Limits?;@_x0036__x002e_1_x003a__x0020_Nam,1.4 Authorising Officer;@_x0036__x002e_1a_x003a__x0020_Di,1.6 Asset Owner Ref.;@_x0036__x002e_1b_x003a__x0020_Ad,1.1 Asset Owner Street Name and Town;@_x0036__x002e_1c_x003a__x0020_Co,1.2 Telephone;@_x0036__x002e_1e_x003a__x0020_Ot,7.0 Other Relevant Information;@NewColumn12,D1 Status;@Acres,Site Area (Acres);@Do_x0020_you_x0020_hold_x0020_Ti,4.1 Do you hold Title Documents?;@If_x0020_Legal_x0020_has_x0020_b,4.4 Legal Team Contact Details;@D1_x0020_Form_x0020_Admin_x0020_,D1 Form Admin Status;@NewD1for,D1 form - new item created;@_x0031__x002e_3_x0020_E_x002d_Ma,1.3 E-Mail;@_x0031__x002e_9_x0020_Department,1.7 Department/Sponsor Body;@_x0031__x002e_10_x0020_Main_x002,1.8 Main Contact in Sponsor Dept or Body;@_x0032__x002e_6_x0020_Current_x0,2.6 Current Net Book Value;@_x0032__x002e_7_x0020_Date_x0020,2.7 Date Net book value provided;@_x0032__x002e_8_x0020_LPS_x0020_,2.8 LPS Valuation Required;@_x0032__x002e_9_x0020_Valuation_,2.9 Valuation within last 12 months?;@_x0032__x002e_10_x0020_Valued_x0,2.10 Valued by;@_x0032__x002e_11_x0020_Previous_,2.11 Previous LPS Case Ref;@_x0032__x002e_12_x0020_Link_x002,2.12 Link to Asset Management Plan;@_x0032__x002e_13_x0020_Year_x002,2.13 Year Capital Receipt Reqd.;@_x0032__x002e_14_x0020_Last_x002,2.14 Last Operational Use Category;@_x0032__x002e_14a_x0020_Other_x0,2.14a Other Use Category;@_x0032__x002e_18_x0020_Private_x,2.18 Private Sector Interest;@_x0032__x002e_19_x0020_Public_x0,2.19 Public Sector Interest;@_x0032__x002e_18a_x0020_Details_,2.18a Details of Private Sector Interest;@_x0032__x002e_19a_x0020_Details_,2.19a Details of Public Sector Interest;@_x0032__x002e_20_x0020_Any_x0020,2.20 Any Current/Pending Planning Decisions?;@_x0032__x002e_20a_x0020_Details_,2.20a Details of Current/Pending Planning Decisions;@Do_x0020_You_x0020_Hold_x0020_Fo,3.5 Do You Hold Former Owner details?;@_x0034__x002e_3_x0020_Do_x0020_y,4.2 Do you have a Title Report?;@_x0034__x002e_3_x0020_Has_x0020_,4.3 Has Your Legal Team Been Instructed?;@_x0035__x002e_0_x0020_Occupation,5.1 Occupation Status;@_x0035__x002e_1_x0020_Basis_x002,5.2 Basis of Occupation;@_x0035__x002e_4_x0020_Current_x0,5.5 Current Rent;@_x0035__x002e_5_x0020_Vacant_x00,5.6 Vacant Possession Date in Lease;@_x0035__x002e_6_x0020_Vacant_x00,5.7 Actual Vacant Possession Date;@_x0035__x002e_7_x0020_Annual_x00,5.8 Annual Vacant Holding Costs;@_x0035__x002e_8_x0020_Details_x0,5.9 Details of Illegal Use;@_x0036__x002e_1_x0020_Are_x0020_,6.0 Are there any Wayleaves?;@_x0036__x002e_1_x0020_Easements,6.1 Easements;@_x0036__x002e_2_x0020_Rights_x00,6.2 Rights of Way;@_x0036__x002e_3_x0020_Restrictiv,6.3 Restrictive Covenants;@_x0036__x002e_4_x0020_Rights_x00,6.4 Rights of Re-entry;@_x0036__x002e_5_x0020_Possessory,6.5 Possessory Title Claims;@_x0036__x002e_6_x0020_Reservatio,6.6 Reservations;@UpdatedD,D1 form - item updated;@_x0033__x002e_3a_x0020_Describe_,3.3a Describe the nature of the material change;@_x0031__x002e_1a_x0020_Post_x002,1.1 Asset Owner Post Code;@D1_x0020_Refernce_x0020_Number,D1 Reference Number;@_x0032__x002e_0_x0020_Town,2.0 Town;@_x0031__x002e_5_x0020_Email,1.5 Email of Submitting Officer;@_x0032__x002e_4a_x0020_E_x0020_P,2.4a E Pims Ref Number;@_x0036__x002e_7_x0020_Is_x0020_t,6.7 Is the Property a Listed Building or Scheduled Monument?;@_x0035__x002e_0_x0020_Ownership_,5.0 Ownership Details;@ID,ID;@ContentType,Content Type;@Modified,Modified;@Created,Created;@Author,Created By;@Editor,Modified By;@_UIVersionString,Version;@Attachments,Attachments;@File_x0020_Type,File Type;@FileLeafRef,Name (for use in forms);@FileDirRef,Path;@FSObjType,Item Type;@_HasCopyDestinations,Has Copy Destinations;@_CopySource,Copy Source;@ContentTypeId,Content Type ID;@_ModerationStatus,Approval Status;@_UIVersion,UI Version;@Created_x0020_Date,Created;@FileRef,URL Path;@ItemChildCount,Item Child Count;@FolderChildCount,Folder Child Count;@AppAuthor,App Created By;@AppEditor,App Modified By;@D1_x0020_Status,D1 Status;@Reason_x0020_For_x0020_Rejection,Referred to Asset Owner Reason;@Related_x0020_D1,Related D1;@D1Regist,D1 Register - Item updated;@Status_x0020_Notes,Status Notes;@Current_x0020_Net_x0020_Book_x00,Current Net Book Value;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Valuation,Date of Valuation;@NewD1Reg,D1 Register - Item created;@Trim_x0020_Reference,HPRM Reference;@CAU_x0020_AO_x0020_Case,CAU AO Case;@District_x0020_AO_x0020_Case,District AO Case;@CAU_x0020_Refernce_x0020_Number,CAU Reference Number;@D1_x0020_Reference_x0020_Number,D1 Reference Number;@Submitting_x0020_Organisation,Submitting Organisation;@EOI_x0020_Circulation,EOI Distribution List;@SubmittedBy,SubmittedBy;@Submitting_x0020_Officer,Submitting Officer;@EOI_x0020_Responses,EOI &apos;No&apos; Responses;@EOI_x0020_Respone_x003d_Yes_x002,Questionnaire circulation;@EOI_x0020_Yes_x0020_responses,EOI &apos;Yes&apos; responses;@EOI_x0020_Reminder_x0020_Date,Next_Reminder_Date;@District_x0020_Valuer,LPS Valuer;@Valuation,LPS Valuation;@Link_x0020_to_x0020_Related_x002,Link to Related D1;@Reason_x0020_for_x0020_Rejection0,Reason for Rejection;@TaskCompleteTarget,TaskCompleteTarget-EOI;@InfoSharingTaskCompleteTarget,TaskCompleteTarget-InfoSharing;@QuestionnaireTaskCompleteTarget,TaskCompleteTarget-Questionnaire;@EOI_x0020_Response_x0020_Target,EOI Response Target;@Questionnaire_x0020_Response_x00,Questionnaire Response Target;@Questionnaire_x0020_Qualifying_x,Questionnaire Qualifying Response Target;@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_Central_x002,Sale to Central Dept (inc ALBs etc.);@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_Council,Sale to Council;@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_HA_x0020_for,Sale to HA for Social Housing;@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_HA_x0020_For0,Sale to HA for Affordable Housing;@Sale_x0020_as_x0020_CAT,Sale as CAT;@Purchaser,Purchaser;@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_Adjacent_x00,Sale to Adjoining Owner;@Sale_x0020_to_x0020_Former_x0020,Sale to Former Owner;@Sale_x0020_on_x0020_Open_x0020_M,Sale on Open Market;@Pathway_x0020_Decision_x0020_Not,Pathway Decision Notes;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Meeting,Date of Meeting;@Purpose_x0020_of_x0020_Meeting,Purpose of Meeting;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Technical_x0,Date of Technical Due Diligence;@Date_x0020_Planning_x0020_Expect,Date Planning Expected;@Date_x0020_Planning_x0020_Achiev,Date Planning Achieved;@Date_x0020_Business_x0020_Plan_x,Date Purchaser&apos;s Business Plan Expected;@Date_x0020_Business_x0020_Plan_x0,Date Purchaser&apos;s Business Plan Achieved;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Council_x002,Date of Council Meeting;@Date_x0020_Full_x0020_Funding_x0,Date Full Funding Expected;@Date_x0020_Legals_x0020_Instruct,Date legals instructed for completion;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Agreed_x0020,Date of Agreed Completion;@Sale_x0020_Agreed_x0020_Figure_x,Sale Agreed Figure (GBP);@Sale_x0020_Figure,Completed Sale Value (GBP);@Date_x0020_Withdrawn,Date Withdrawn;@Date_x0020_Completed,Date Sale Completed;@Date_x0020_Agent_x0020_Appointed,Date Agent Appointed;@Date_x0020_Marketing_x0020_Start,Date Marketing Started;@Current_x0020_Highest_x0020_Bid,Current or Highest Bid;@Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date,Review Date;@D1_x0020_Approved_x0020_date,D1_Approved_Date;@D1_EOI_Date,D1_EOI_Date;@D1_Questionnaire_Date,D1_Issue_Questionnaire_Date;@D1_Q_Published_Date,D1_Release_Questionnaire_Date;@D1_Rejected_Date,D1_Rejected_Date;@D1_NilCirc_Date,D1_NilCirc_Date;@Milestones,Milestones;@Technical_x0020_Due_x0020_Dillig,Technical Due Dilligence Notes;@Date_x0020_Asset_x0020_Owners_x0,Date Asset Owners Business Plan Expected for CAT;@Date_x0020_Asset_x0020_Owner_x00,Date Asset Owner&apos;s Business Plan Achieved for CAT;@Date_x0020_Full_x0020_funding_x00,Date Full funding Achieved;@Date_x0020_Sale_x0020_Agreed,Date Sale Agreed;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Current_x002,Date of Current or Highest Bid/Offer;@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Closure_x002,Date of Closure of Bids/Offers;@Address,Address;</datafields>

<XSL>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="dvt_firstrow">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="dvt_nextpagedata" />
<xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowLimit" select="10" />
    <xsl:variable name="FirstRow" select="$dvt_firstrow" />
    <xsl:variable name="LastRow">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($FirstRow + $RowLimit - 1) &gt; $dvt_RowCount"><xsl:value-of select="$dvt_RowCount" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow + $RowLimit - 1" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.empty"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Row</th>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Milestones</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows[position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
        <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
        <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
        <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
        <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
        <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="number(ddwrt:NameChanged('',-100))" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_KeepItemsTogether" select="false()" />
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_HideGroupDetail" select="false()" />
        <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow) or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether">
            <xsl:if test="not($dvt_HideGroupDetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="string($XPath)" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_3"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.empty">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText">There are no items to show in this view.</xsl:variable>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb">
                <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_2_automode">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template name="dvt_2">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="D1_Form/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2.empty"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_2_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_2.body">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2.rowview"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_2.rowview">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_2_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="string($XPath)" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@NewColumn12"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Address_x0020_of_x0020_Asset"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@_x0032__x002e_0_x0020_Town"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Post_x0020_Code_x0020_of_x0020_A"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_2.empty" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText"></xsl:variable>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb">
                <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_3_automode">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template name="dvt_3">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="D1_Register/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_3.empty"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_3_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_3.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_3.body">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_3.rowview"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_3.rowview">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_3_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="string($XPath)" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Milestones"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_3.empty" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText"></xsl:variable>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb">
                <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
    <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
    <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <xsl:if test="$FirstRow &gt; 1 or $LastRow &lt; $dvt_RowCount">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.navigation">
                    <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="$RealLastRow" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.navigation">
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
    <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
    <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
    <xsl:variable name="PrevRow">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$FirstRow - $RowLimit &lt; 1">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow - $RowLimit" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="LastRowValue">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$LastRow &gt; $RealLastRow">
                <xsl:value-of select="$LastRow"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RealLastRow"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="NextRow">
        <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue + 1"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-paging" align="right">
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_firstrow &gt; 1" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('dvt_firstrow={1}')" />;</xsl:attribute>
            Start</a>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',$PrevRow,'}'))" />;</xsl:attribute>
            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/prev.gif" border="0" alt="Previous" />
            </a>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow" />
         - <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$LastRowValue &lt; $dvt_RowCount or string-length($dvt_nextpagedata)!=0" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',$NextRow,'}'))" />;</xsl:attribute>
            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next" />
            </a>
        </xsl:if>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </XSL>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

Comment: please share your XSLT code

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri I've added the code as requested

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
<tr valign="top">
   <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
       <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
   </xsl:if>
   <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Row</th>
   <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Milestones</th>
</tr>
```

You should have as many `<th>`'s as the numebr of `<td>`'s in any specific row.

So if you change it with the following, you should see the desired result:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
    </xsl:if>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Row</th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">NewColumn12</th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Address of Asset</th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Town</th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Post Code</th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Milestones</th>
</tr>
```

NOTE: Change the column names as you desire.

Comment: Once I tried this solution, it simply added empty columns onto the end of my table. I think the problem is that the data of view one is being registered under a single column, 'Row' and the data of view two is being registered under 'Milestone' which is correct.